# How to get status of UPS?

Tags: c++, c

i need to communicate to UPS from my application.my system is connected to UPS and i need to get the status of that UPS which will help me to identify that system is going to down, so that i can take backup of my files.

I am very new to this.so please give me some more idea how to do this and if you can share some c/c++ code will be very helpful.

If anyone need more details please let me know.

Thanks,
Deepesh

Comment: Is this UNIX, Windows, or something embedded?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the application domain you do not need to get the status of the UPS or talk to the UPS at all.

You should respond to the operating system's requests to your application to quit and perform whatever backup operations you application deems necessary. If your target systems are connected to a UPS they should be set up so that the operating system responds to the appropriate "on battery" or "battery low" signals.

This important for at least two reasons. First, you do not tie your application to a specific UPS interface, model or vendor. Second your application will be robust when a non-UPS initiated shutdown (application or system wide) occurs.

The added bonus is that responding to the operating system quit request is likely to be something that you do anyway.